# dojo equivalent for event .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, dom-events

What is the equivalent code in dojo for this snippet of jQuery?

```
 $(".box").change(function() { }
```

Comment: What kind of event are you expecting from your `.box` elements? Dojo has event hooks of various kinds, but it's not clear to me what you expect to have happen from this example.

Comment: i have a drop down menu with options, so, when i change the menu i need to redraw a chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dojo uses Qt based connect/disconnect event handling.

```
dojo.query(".box").connect("onchange", function(){});
```

or more familiar to jQuery

```
dojo.query(".box").onchange(function(){});
```

see the section "events" in
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/using_query/